# pipe custom message and grep together to mutt

Tags: grep, command-line-interface, echo, mutt

i want to grep a logfile and send it via mutt to my email address.
Additionally i would like to send an text with my email.

```
echo | grep "ERROR" logFile.log  | mutt -s "ERROR Messages" myemail@gmail.com -a logFile.log
```

This works fine. I grep my logfile and echo it as body in my email to myemail@gmail.com with the logfile attached. 
But i would also like to add an message like : " This is an automatic email generated" additionally to my grep output.
How to pipe it ?

To understand [mutt](https://www.garron.me/en/go2linux/send-mail-gmail-mutt.html) :

```
echo "This is the body" | mutt -s "Testing mutt" user@yahoo.com -a /tmp/XDefd.png
```

instead  of "This is the body" iam using the output of grep but i would also like to put an custom message in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute several commands in a subprocess and pipe the whole output to mutt:

```
(cat fixedmessage.txt;
 grep "ERROR" logFile.log) |
mutt -s "ERROR Messages" myemail@gmail.com -a logFile.log
```